# Pandas в Colab. После groupby столбец ..."уходит"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

Прошу прощения за корявый заголовок вопроса.

Есть dataframe, делаю по левому столбцу groupby и заношу результат в другой dataframe . И столбец.. "превращается в номер строки". При выгрузке он просто отсутствует. В чём секрет, подскажите пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Понял, спасибо, не знал.
Если бы столбец не пропадал при выгрузке в csv (.to_csv), не  обратил бы внимания.

Comment: Как можно здесь поблагодарить за ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В методе [DataFrame.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) есть аргумент `as_index=True`, который по умолчанию - истина. В результате столбцы группировки (а их может быть несколько), становятся индексом (или мультииндексом, если их несколько). Чтобы изменить такое поведение и не "переносить" столбцы в индекс, нужно явно задать `as_index=False`.

Comment: И собственно это поведение логично - после группировки и агрегации старый индекс не имеет смысла, а поле группировки после агрегации уникально и может быть использовано как индекс.